# Powershell: Count instances of strings in a file using a list

Tags: windows, unix, powershell, grep

I am trying to get the number of times a string (varying from 40 to 400+ characters) in "file1" occurs in "file2" in an effective way.  file1 has about 2k lines and file2 has about 130k lines.  I currently have a Unix solution that does it in about 2 mins in a VM and about 5 in [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), but I am trying to do it with Powershell/Python since the files are in windows and I am using the output in excel and use it with automation (AutoIT.)
I have a solution, but it takes WAY too long (in about the same times that the Cygwin finished - all 2k lines - I had only 40-50 lines in Powershell!)
Although I haven't prepare a solution yet, I am open to use Python as well if there is a solution that can be fast and accurate.

Here is the Unix Code:

```
while read SEARCH_STRING; 
do printf "%s$" "${SEARCH_STRING}"; 
grep -Fc "${SEARCH_STRING}" file2.csv; 
done < file1.csv | tee -a output.txt;
```

And here is the Powershell code I currently have

```
$Target = Get-Content .\file1.csv
Foreach ($line in $Target){
    #Just to keep strings small, since I found that not all
    #strings were being compared correctly if they where 250+ chars
    $line = $line.Substring(0,180)
    $Coll = Get-Content .\file2.csv | Select-string -pattern "$line"
    $cnt = $Coll | measure
    $cnt.count
}
```

Any ideas of suggestions will help.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm trying a modified solution suggested by C.B.

```
del .\output.txt
$Target = Get-Content .\file1.csv
$file= [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText( "C:\temp\file2.csv" )
Foreach ($line in $Target){
    $line = [string]$line.Substring(0, $line.length/2)
    $cnt = [regex]::matches( [string]$file, $line).count  >> ".\output.txt" 
}
```

But, since my strings in file1 are varying in length I keept getting OutOfBound exceptions for the SubString function, so I halved (/2) the input string to try to get a match. And when I try to halve them, if I it had an open parentheses, it tells me this:

```
Exception calling "Matches" with "2" argument(s): "parsing "CVE-2013-0796,04/02/2013,MFSA2013-35 SeaMonkey: WebGL
crash with Mesa graphics driver on Linux (C" - Not enough )'s."
At C:\temp\script_test.ps1:6 char:5
+     $cnt = [regex]::matches( [string]$file, $line).count  >> ".\output.txt ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

I don't know if there is a way to raise the input limit in powershell (My biggest size at the moment is 406, but could be bigger in the future) or just give up and try a Python solution.

Thoughts?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @C.B. I got the correct answer and it matches the output of the Bash script perfectly. Here is the full code that outputs results to a text file:

```
$Target = Get-Content .\file1.csv
$file= [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText( "C:\temp\file2.csv" )
Foreach ($line in $Target){
    $cnt = [regex]::matches( $file, [regex]::escape($line)).count  >> ".\output.txt"    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$Target = Get-Content .\file1.csv
$file= [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText( "c:\test\file2.csv" )
Foreach ($line in $Target){
    $line = $line.Substring(0,180)    
    $cnt = [regex]::matches( $file, [regex]::escape($line)).count    
}
```

Comment: It works great and fast (about a minute for all results!) Although I have one more issue now... Its citing an OurOfRange exception for the SubString function (understandable since some Strings aren't 180 chars long) and doesn't give me the correct results for many instances, sometimes outputting 0 matches and even skipping reading it altogether. Any type of fix for a character limit in PowerShell?

Comment: You can try: `$line = $line.Substring(0, $line.length -1)`

Comment: Did so, but I have variable lengths in my file1. And those strings contain parentheses and, for some reason, if I cut a string with an open parentheses it gives an Argument exception since there are "not enough ')'s ". Did a if/else evaluation but didn't help much either and keep getting no matches in some fields. Thinking of using Python with regex...

Comment: @lennin59 Try now. I've edited my answer escaping the $line string value

Comment: That did it! And it works without using the substring function. I'll modify my question to reflect the answer. Thanks a lot @C.B.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your script is that you read `file2.csv` over and over again, for each line from `file1.csv`. Reading the file just once and storing the content in a variable should significantly speed things up. Try this:

```
$f2 = Get-Content .\file2.csv

foreach ($line in (gc .\file1.csv)) {
  $line = $line.Substring(0,180)
  @($f2 | ? { $_ -match $line }).Count
}
```

Comment: You're right about me checking the file over and over again, but I tried your method and didn't sped things up that much. Thanks for the tip though!